# How do I fetch data without cloudflare in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, http, fetch, cloudflare

The fetch doesn't work

```js
const response = await fetch(url)
const html = await response.json()
```

It returns a page with Cloudflare!

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to bypass cloudflare you can either try this package **[cloudscraper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudscraper)** or you can get the content using a headless Chrome and the popular is **[Puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer)**.